# How do I enforce a URL redirect when API URL suffix is not passed for my API Management

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, ibm-api-management

**I have looked into the Rewrite URL for azure APIM but I don't know if this is the right approach as it looks like its more for the operations**

I have an API Management instance (https://my-apim.azure-api.net) with 2 APIs:

AP1 1:- https://my-apim.azure-api.net/api1

AP1 2:- https://my-apim.azure-api.net/api2

I want to implement a case where the APIM redirects to the login page (e.g https://www.mywebsite.com/login) if my APIM is called without the API suffix (e.g. "/api2").

How would I go about this?

Comment: Hi, please refer to the solution I provided below. If it helps your problem, please [accept it as answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) (click on the check mark beside my answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in). Thanks in advance~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"All APIs" policy is executed for every request APIM receives. on-error section, among other cases, is executed if received request is not matched with any operation registered in APIM. See this doc on how to handle errors like 404 and others: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-error-handling-policies, but in short, adding something like below into on-error at All APIs scope should do the trick:

```
<choose>
  <when condition="@(context.LastError.Reason == "OperationNotFound")">
    <return-response>
      <set-status code="307" reason="Temporary Redirect"/>
      <set-header name="Location" exists-action="override">
        <value>https://www.mywebsite.com/login</value>
      </set-header>
    </return-response>
  </when>
</choose>
```

You can implement additional checks to specifically target scenario when suffix is not  provided, but above will cover all cases when URI in does not match any operation.

Answer (score 0):

For your requirement, it seems `rewrite-uri` policy can't implement it. Please refer to my steps below:

**1.** I have two apis(which same with yours) in my APIM instance.

[image]

**2.** Then click "Add API" to create another api, we can name it with `root`. And set your login url as the "**Web service URL**"

[image]

**3.** After that, add operation in the newly created api `root`. Provide the display and just type `/` to the "URL" input box.

[image]

**4.** Now you can test request your APIM url `https://my-apim.azure-api.net` without `api1/api2`, it will redirect to your login page.